# Jquery datepicker not working inside v-for of Vue.js component in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, datepicker

Jquery date picker showing strange behavior inside the v-for loop in my vue.js component. Outside of the loop, it is working fine and date picker is showing. But, inside my v-for loop, it is not picking date picker as expected.

Here is my working code of date picker. (Working Case)

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="date" class="col-form-label pt-0">For Week End</label>
        <input type="text" :name="`payrolls[${i}][payrol_date]`" class="form-control datepickere">
    </div>
</div>
```

Date picker not working in this case (Non-working case)

```
<div v-for="(pay_roll, i) in payrolls" class="border border-primary p-3 rounded mb-3" :key="pay_roll.id">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="date" class="col-form-label pt-0">For Week End</label>
            <input type="text" :name="`payrolls[${i}][payrol_date]`" class="form-control datepickere">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery code of datepicker.

```
$(".datepickere").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        display("Selected date: " + dateText + ", Current Selected Value= " + this.value);
      $(this).change();
    }
}).on("change", function() {
    display("Change event");
});
function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

Although I have given a class instead of an id, still problem is the same. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a typo in your code. Change datepickere to datepicker and it should work. Also, if I was you, I would use a vue compatible datepicker such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker.